# Cite translator with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, citing, translate

I have many references in my document with translator field. Is there any possibility to cite directly the translator(s) of the document using `biblatex` with a command such as `\citetranslator`?

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article} 
\listfiles
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{article,
  author = {Nachname, Vorname},
  title = {Titel des Zeitschriftenartikels},
  journal = {Zeitschrift},
  year = {2006},
  volume = {6},
  translator = {Talu, Jean},
  pages = {19--75}
}

\end{filecontents}


\usepackage[main=french,ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}


%bibliographie
\usepackage[
usetranslator=true,
bibstyle=verbose,
citestyle=verbose-ibid,
autocite=footnote, 
language=french]{biblatex}

\bibliography{\jobname}


\begin{document}
\cite{article}
\citetranslator{article}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I have found a solution

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citetrans}
  {\boolfalse{citetracker}%
   \boolfalse{pagetracker}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\ifnameundef{translator}
     {\printtext{ERROR}}
     {\printnames[default]{translator}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

**NB:**

`\printtext{ERROR}` could be removed (it shows ERROR if no translator are specified)

`\printnames[default]{translator}` this command show the first and last name of the translators. Removing `default` leads to a different order: in my case I obtain `LAST, First`.

Comment: `\citename{foo}{translator}` is also possible